# Почему singleton не статический класс?

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Почему Singleton он же одиночке - не статический класс?
Почему это уникальный экземпляр класса, а не просто класс со статическими полями и методами.
Разве результат не один и тот же (нечто, представляющие себя в единственном числе)?

Дополнительно:
Нужен класс с методом, который выполняет определённую проверку некоего файла. Что предпочтительней: создать статический класс со статическим методом, который принимает параметром метода файл и проверяет его или же создать класс (которому при создании объекта в конструкторе передается файл), имеющий  метод, вызываемый у экземпляра объекта, проверяющий этот файл.

Comment: Статический класс подразумевает то, что у него **все** методы статические. У синглтона - могут быть и обычные методы

Comment: @СергейМишин Ну это понятно. Но если объект класса (синглтон) всё равно в одном экземпляре и все его данные в одном экземпляре, зачем тогда нужен этот экземпляр, если статика  тоже в единственном числе.

Comment: шшшшшшшшшшшшто?

Comment: Со временем может появиться необходимость создавать другие экземпляры этого класса. Тогда он полностью безболезненно эволюционирует в обычный класс. Если бы он был статическим классом, и к этому моменту было бы написана уже не одна тысяча строк кода, для этого потребовались бы колоссальные изменения во всем проекте.

Answer (score 1):

Главная причина сделать динамический экземпляр с динамическими методами - это возможность наследования.

Статические методы НЕ НАСЛЕДУЮТСЯ.

Поэтому, при возникновении необходимости вариативного создания синглтоновского экземпляра в зависимости от входящих параметров более предпочтительна реализация с динамическим созданием экземпляра.

Для маленького проекта с простой функциональностью - совершенно без разницы как делать чисто статические или динамические. Но если вдруг понадобится расширять проект, то реализация с динамическими методами более гибкая.